# Generating the maximum number possible from an array

Tags: algorithm, programming-challenge, scala

I have the following code in Scala as a solution to the problem:

> Find the maximum number possible from the given Seq of Integers while keeping the individual numbers intact

e.g.

> Seq(2,5,9,4) should result in 9542
>
> Seq(4, 98, 10, 110, 91) should result in 9891411010

Note that in case of numbers with more than one digit, the entire number should remain together.

Solution in Scala:

```
import scala.util.Sorting
object MatheMagic {
  def getLargestPossibleNumber(numArray: Seq[Int]) = {
    numArray.sorted[Int](IntOrdering).mkString.toLong
  }
  object IntOrdering extends Ordering[Int] {
    def compare(x: Int, y: Int) = {
      -(x.toString.concat(y.toString).toInt compare y.toString.concat(x.toString).toInt)
    }
  }
}
```

Sample invocation:

```
MatheMagic.getLargestPossibleNumber(Seq(4, 98, 10, 110, 91))
```

Comment: LGTM, though I'm not sure how I would actually prove that the algorithm always gives the correct answer.

Comment: @SethTisue I would compare it to bruteforce on some randomly generated testcases

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that an induction proof would work just fine. Haven't done one in ages though.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is good, but the implementation is a bit wasteful:

- In `IntOrdering.compare`, `x` and `y` are converted to String twice, and then converted to `Int`

  - It's especially bad since the numbers in the sequence may pass through `compare` multiple times in different pairs, and get converted to String even more times
- You could reduce the casts:

  - Convert all numbers to `String` once in the beginning
  - Compare as strings. The algorithm will work with alphabetical comparison too
  - Convert to `Long` once at the end
- Creating a custom `Ordering` seems a bit overkill

This one-liner will do the job:

```
nums.map(_.toString).sortWith(
  (a, b) => (a concat b).compareTo(b concat a) > 0).mkString.toLong
```